# Word for "lunch" + "dinner" eaten late?

Tags: word-request

A late breakfast/early lunch combination meal is called "brunch". Is there a parallel term for the afternoon?

**What do I call "lunch" joined with "dinner"?**

---

Note that I don't mean a meal eaten *between* lunch and dinner, but a meal that serves the purpose of both lunch and dinner.

Comment: When speaking with a friend of mine, I was used to say _lunner_, a word I coined basing on _brunch_; sometimes I use _blunner_. `;)`

Comment: @WendiKidd Please not change question to something else. _How to call in English "launch" + "dinner" eat late?_ is not _Phrase for a meal between lunch and dinner_. It is illogical the last meal can not be meal between lunch and dinner - is not it?

Comment: @Chameleon, you'll need to add some more detail... to me the edit made perfect sense.  You're looking for the name of a meal that you eat after the normal lunch time but before the normal dinner time?

Comment: @Hellion You want to answer something else more detailed? :) Question is simple how to call "launch" + "dinner" - for example you go on vacation and you have two meals in offer - **the first breakfast** and **the last "launch" + "dinner"**.

Comment: @Hellion BTW Polish eats such meals breakfast (first breakfast), second breakfast (optional and lite), dinner (large - 2 dishes first soup, second not soup + salad - some times 3rd dish desert + tea, coffee), _before supper_ (original name - optional and lite), supper. We not have launch and eat dinner later than launch :) Polish meals is different than English - supper is lite and dinner is heavy in Poland - launch is very small and dine/supper very large and late in England. It is significant difference.

Comment: @Chameleon, So, in Poland you have Breakfast, second breakfast, dinner, "pre-supper", and supper.  You'd like to know what a proper English word for this "pre-supper" meal would be?

Comment: The title didn't really make sense from an English perspective; I was trying to improve the question, though I see now that you meant something else. Meals are done differently here; we have 3 main meals (morning, noon, and evening) and we come up with odd words for the ones between (ex. brunch between morning and noon). So from an English perspective, the only way to interpret your title was "a meal between lunch and dinner" (which is why Hellion understood the edit as I did). I hope that explains my edit; my main goal was to fix the spelling of *lunch*, so I'll do that now & leave the rest.

Comment: Second breakfast? Sounds like those of us with hobbit tendencies ought to move to Poland. :) (Though of course I think what you're talking about are merely the equivalents of the Hungarian *tízórai* "snack eaten at 10 a.m." and *uzsonna* "afternoon snack".) Also, careful of the word "dinner": in my neck of the woods, it means exactly the same thing as "supper". The meal we eat at or around noon is only ever "lunch".

Comment: @WendiKidd You should not **never change context** but do more good with fixing errors or improving context - **context changes** annoys me or makes me confused - some other peoples may feel it the same. I was in England some time ago - your meals are different than in other countries - I am feeling very hungry during lunch and too full after dinner. When I go on vacation is common that is offered "lunch" + "dinner" at about 18:00 to have whole day free.

Comment: @Martha Second breakfast is very common in Poland. I give you example: 1st breakfast (always 6:00-9:00 medium, water/tea/coffee/milk!), 2nd breakfast (optional but often 10:00-12:00 small - sandwich), dinner (always 12:00-17:00 large, soup, hot dish, salad + optional desert), before supper (rare 15:00-17:00 small, water/tea + sandwich or lite cake), supper (always 19:00-21:00 medium, water/tea/milk!, hot or not). We produce a lot of food so eating local very good food is common. Maybe hobbits little base on Polish (it created during 2nd WW where Polish fights in many places).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Words for meals in English are:

breakfast: first meal of the day, eaten in the morning

lunch: a meal eaten around noon

supper: a meal eaten in the evening

dinner: the biggest meal of the day. For most Americans that's the same as supper, though some people have their big meal at lunch time and so call that dinner.

brunch: a meal too late to normally be called breakfast and too early to be lunch, and/or which takes the place of breakfast and lunch.

There is no commonly-used word for a late lunch or early dinner or supper. Dinner times vary pretty widely. A big meal eaten anywhere between about 5:00 pm and 10:00 pm would routinely be called supper or dinner and no one would consider that strange. People sometimes say "we had an early dinner" or "we eat supper late" to distinguish.

Comment: Americans often eat Sunday dinner in the afternoon, as well as on Thanksgiving, Christmas, and Easter.  English generally have breakfast, dinner and "tea" in my experience.  I lived there when "school dinners" went up a "whole tanner" to 1/6, so it was rather a long time ago.  I suspect the mashed potatoes in said dinners haven't changed much in 40 years, however.

Comment: To expand a bit on BobRodes'comment - particularly in Northern England, it can also be: breakfast in the morning; dinner - large meal at midday; and tea - lighter meal around 5 or 6; then supper - snack before bed such as a couple of biscuits and a mug of Ovaltine. The usage and meaning of 'lunch', 'dinner' and 'supper' carries a significant weight of class and regional identification to a BrEng ear

Comment: I should have clarified that I was giving American usage. Yes, the British also have "tea", I have no idea what Australians call their meals, etc. @BobRodes Yes, while most Americans have their big meal in the evening, on special occasions like Christmas and Thanksgiving we typically have a big meal in the middle of the day, and thus call that "Christmas dinner" or "Thanksgiving dinner".

Comment: In our family we did that on Christmas, Thanksgiving, and Easter.  When I was growing up there were a few kids whose families had Sunday dinner in the afternoon.  This was a very prevalent tradition among Catholics until the second half of the 20th century, when the rules for fasting before Mass were changed.  Up until then, fasting was required from the time you got up until the time you received Communion at Mass.  So, the 12:15 Mass didn't exist, and people usually had a big meal right afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I have been hearing the term "[linner](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Linner)" a lot around me lately (Boston, USA) to mean "lunch" joined with "dinner".

[Example](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/theatre-dance/features/my-edinburgh-lucy-porter-comedian-1769832.html) :

> I didn't eat breakfast until about 11.30 because I've started getting
> up a bit later. So mid-afternoon lunch is the last time I'll eat
> before my 8.20 show, and technically counts as dinner as well. Call it
> linner or dunch. It's usually a quick sandwich.

Alternatives: [luner](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=luner), [lunner](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lunner) and [lupper](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lupper).

Note that the word [dunch](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dunch) has a different meaning:

> A small meal between lunch and dinner in the late afternoon or early
> evening (about 3-5 p.m.), usually including tea or coffee with
> cookies, sometimes fruits, a salad or a light sandwich.
>
> *"For tomorrow, I have already scheduled lunch and dinner with my colleagues. Let's have a dunch together."*

I believe that none of those words are in any official dictionary though, only proposed:

- https://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/545/linner
- https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/linner

Comment: If anyone said that to me I'd respond with, "*Dunch*, ha ha, good one.  Ok 'dunch' it is."

Comment: Unfortunately I am not native enough to make fun of people speaking English :)

Comment: IMO, brunch is the only combination in regular usage.  All the others are "Wortspielen" based on logical cognates of the word brunch.

Comment: "none of those words are in any official dictionary though" Nor are they in common use, to the best of my knowledge. I've heard people say "linner", but mostly as a joke. Of course they might catch on in time, but they're not there yet.