# Breakfast + lunch = brunch ; lunch + dinner = linner ; breakfast + lunch + dinner =?

Tags: word-request, time

Is there any word to designate a meal that serves as breakfast, lunch and dinner? (i.e. only meal of the day)

Comment: Where did you get "linner"?  People might occasionally use it in a joking one-off way, but it's not a serious word.

Comment: @Jim http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/29973/3023

Comment: Yes, and that usage is what I'd call a joking usage- the person using it knows it's not a real word but is trying to be cute. As evidenced, by- "*call it linner or dunch, or luner, lunner, lupper*" and all from the urban dictionary which has some value for certain situations, but one must be extremely careful how one interprets information found there.

Comment: @Jim Sure, thanks for the warning. I am curious to know whether there exists a similar word to designate a meal that serves as breakfast, lunch and dinner, even if only used jokingly.

Comment: Since we're just making words up: Berliner!

Comment: @VotetoClose A meal that is so big, that it's the only meal you eat all day.

Comment: "Here is your *one meal for the day*." I don't think there's a word for it.

Comment: I personally use "linner"... though "dunch" is amusing to me.... but it's in the wrong order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically the meal is named for the time-frame in which it occurs.

- Breakfast: early morning
- Lunch: midday
- Dinner/Supper: early
  evening (although dinner can also be noon to early-afternoon
  especially on Sundays and holidays, and whether the evening meal is
  called dinner or supper varies regionally as well.)

If the meal falls outside the "normal" time-frame it is modified: late dinner, late breakfast, early lunch, late lunch.

Terms like Brunch combines *two* elements of a meal- time-frame and menu. Brunch, combining Breakfast and Lunch, is usually eaten mid-morning, in-between the normal breakfast and lunch time-frame, and usually consists of both breakfast and lunch foods.

There's not as much of a distinction between Lunch and Dinner menu items so there really isn't a separate word combining Lunch and Dinner.  It's either a *late lunch* or an *early dinner* (depending which meals you've already eaten or plan to eat.)

To combine all three meals into one you'd typically modify it with "Big" and then choose the term appropriate for the time-frame in which it was taken.
A "Big Breakfast," a "Big Lunch", a "Big Dinner" etc.
There's no need for a separate word because all the time-frames are adequately covered.
For example:

> We'll be eating a *big lunch* tomorrow so I'm going to skip breakfast and I probably won't be hungry for supper later.
>
> I ate such a *big breakfast* that I think I probably won't eat again until tomorrow.
>
> The *brunch* at Hotel del Coronado was huge! I couldn't possibly eat anything more for the rest of the day.
>
> *Dinner* is at 1:00pm tomorrow. We're going all out, so come hungry and be prepared to not eat for the rest of the day.

Answer (score 2):

I would just call it a daily meal.

Answer (score 1):

Ditch dinner, since that actually can refer to either the noon meal or the last meal of the day. Use "supper" instead. Then say

*Brupper*

**br**eakfast
l**u**nch
su**pper**

It's made up, but so is "linner." And if this question is allowed to stand, so should this answer.